# zenbook ux330uak : fan problem, print finger problem ... how to install drinvers?

Tags: drivers, updates, fan, fingerprint-reader

I have ASUS Zenbook UX330UAK version.

I bought this laptop with Windows 10 OS, and everything seems okay then I switched to Ubuntu (see version) :

```
mostafa@mostafa-UX330UAK:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Focal Fossa (development branch)
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

my problems are :

- Finger print is not working
- Fan is very noisy and my keyboard becomes very hot
- It takes time when I switch between windows

When I try to upgrade my system i returns me this Error message  :

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
Transaction failed: Package dependencies cannot be resolved
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libmutter-6-0: Depends: mutter-common (>= 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) but 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libgbm1 (>= 17.1.0~rc2) but 20.0.4-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libgudev-1.0-0 (>= 232) but 1:233-1 is to be installed
               Depends: libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0) but 2:1.0.10-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libsystemd0 (>= 213) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libudev1 (>= 183) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.2.99.901) but 2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libx11-xcb1 (>= 2:1.6.9) but 2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.4.5) but 1:0.4.5-1 is to be installed
               Depends: libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1) but 1:1.1.5-2 is to be installed
               Depends: libxext6 (>= 2:1.3.0) but 2:1.3.4-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libxfixes3 (>= 1:5.0) but 1:5.0.3-2 is to be installed
               Depends: libxi6 (>= 2:1.6.99.1) but 2:1.7.10-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libxkbfile1 (>= 1:1.1.0) but 1:1.1.0-1 is to be installed
               Depends: libxrandr2 (>= 2:1.5.0) but 2:1.5.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
ubuntu-session: Depends: gnome-session-bin (>= 3.36.0-2ubuntu1) but 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Depends: gnome-session-common (= 3.36.0-2ubuntu1) but 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Depends: yaru-theme-gnome-shell (>= 20.04.3~) but 20.04.7 is to be installed
yaru-theme-gnome-shell:
```

in ASUS website I see no drivers for Ubuntu ! (only for windows)

Comment: Please ask one question per problem. You mentioned 4 here.

Comment: libmutter-6-0 is already installed when you use the 20.04 Desktop installer. It's a required dependency of Gnome Shell. I'm curious why your LSB output says "*development branch" -- mine doesn't. Seems clear that you didn't use the Desktop installer, and you installed some awful wrong-version source. Remove that source. Had you used the Desktop Installer's "Try Ubuntu" environment, you could have tested your hardware before installing.